# Cypress utilizing Gitlab Variables

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress

I am currently using [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io) as my testing tool, and have been running into a slight problem when running it on gitlab ci.

## The Problem

Part of my Cypress test currently uses sensitive Credit Card Information, so when I uploaded it into a gitlab repository I had to try and figure out a way to keep anyone from ever viewing said "sensitive information". Eventually, I tried to utilize Gitlabs handy "Secret Variable" functionality.

After Setting up all of the variables that I needed to stay hidden, I went into my gitlab-ci.yml file and set it up so that the .gitlab-ci.yml file creates a new file called "cypress/support/PaymentCredentials.js", and within that file all of the sensitive payment information will be stored as javascript variables (Shown below)

```
image: bahmutov/cypress-image
# caching node_modules folder
# https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/01/gitlab-runner-with-docker/
cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/
before_script:
  - cypress verify
  - "echo -e \"export default {CARDHOLDER_NAME: '$CARDHOLDER_NAME', CARD_CC: '$CARD_CC', CARD_CC_MONTH: '$CARD_CC_MONTH', CARD_CC_YEAR: '$CARD_CC_YEAR', CARD_CC_CCV: '$CARD_CC_CCV'}\" > cypress/support/PaymentCredentials.js"
stages:
  - build
  - test
build-specs:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - cypress/integration
.job_template: &e2e_test_definition
  script:
    - echo $CARDHOLDER_NAME
    - export $CARDHOLDER_NAME
    - cypress ci --spec "cypress/integration/$CI_BUILD_NAME.js"
Test_Project:
  <<: *e2e_test_definition
```

So in Cypress I set up the Integration file to act like like this:

```
describe('Test', function(){

  afterEach(function(){

  })
  beforeEach(function(){

  })
  //The entire job
  context('Test - Full Functionality Test', function(){
    it('Front-end Walkthrough', function(){
    /*This is going to go through the first step on Test*/
    stepOne()
    /*This is going to go through the Second step on Test*/
    stepTwo()
    /*This is going to go through the Third step on Test*/
    stepThree()
    /*Page loads very slowly, needed some buffer*/
    cy.wait(5000) 
    /*This is going to go through the Fourth step on Test*/
      cy.then(function(){
        cy
        .get('[name=method]').select("CC") //select CC
        .get('#name').type(CARDHOLDER_NAME)
        .get('#number').type(CARD_CC)
        .get('#month').select(CARD_CC_MONTH)
        .get('#year').select(CARD_CC_YEAR)
        .get('#ccv').type(CARD_CC_CCV)
        .get('[type=checkbox]').check({force: true})
        .get('#scoreboard-enroll-form').submit()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

When I ran the Pipeline I still receive an error stating that the "CARDHOLDER_NAME" has not been defined: 
 [Gitlab ci build report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNOmO.png)

Are there any suggested approaches to take for this scenario? Did I get something ridiculous wrong?

Either way, I appreciate any help!

Comment: I realise this isn't related to your question but I am really curious. What was the decision to use something that just supports Chrome and what's so much better about Cypress? I've been working on the Open-source project Courgette https://github.com/canvaspixels/courgette and was wondering what features are drawing everybody towards Cypress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[There are multiple ways to pass a secret variable to a Cypress test.](https://docs.cypress.io/docs/environment-variables#section-option-3-export-as-cypress_) Here are a few ways you could do it:

**Environment Variables in CLI**

- Pass in the secret variables to the `cypress ci` command as an argument to create a Cypress environment variable.

  ```
  cypress ci --env CARDHOLDER_NAME=$CARDHOLDER_NAME,CARD_CC=$CARD_CC
  ```
- Later in your tests, access the Cypress environment variable.

  ```
  Cypress.env('CARDHOLDER_NAME')
  Cypress.env('CARD_CC')
  ```

**Export as CYPRESS_***

- You can export the secret variables as you were trying to do, but you would need to append `CYPRESS_` to the variable to have it accessible in your tests.

  ```
  export CYPRESS_CARD_CC=$CARD_CC
  ```
- Later in your tests, access the exported variables.

  ```
  Cypress.env('CARD_CC')
  ```

**[cy.exec()](https://docs.cypress.io/v1.0/docs/exec)**

- Use Cypress' `exec` to get secret variable's inline.

  ```
  cy.exec("echo $CARDHOLDER_NAME").its("stdout").then(function(stdout){
     cy.get('#name').type(stdout)
  })
  ```